# How to remove "bundle install" command during the project creation in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am creating a new project:

```
rails new ggg --database=mysql
```

and get following output:

```
create  
      create  README
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/images/rails.png
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/mailers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
      create  app/models/.gitkeep
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  doc
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
      create  log
      create  log/.gitkeep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  script
      create  script/rails
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
      create  test/functional
      create  test/functional/.gitkeep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.gitkeep
      create  test/unit
      create  test/unit/.gitkeep
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
```

task "bundle install" takes a lot of time... about 30-40 minutes.

How to remove it?

Comment: About 30-40 minutes ?... Bundle install is necessary the first time you create a project with a specified Rails version and it should last 5 minutes max with a really slow connection and no gems already on the disk.

Comment: @Skydreamer, yep, about that. Even now I am waiting.. dont know what to do. If I skip bundle I get error after running WeBrick "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished)"

Comment: Can you describe (at a high level) your connectivity situation? I can't imagine it taking that long.

Comment: you might be using a network with slow/no connection to the gems server. For me, in China, a VPN is necessary to do things like this

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You want the `--skip-bundle` flag:

```
rails new ggg --database=mysql --skip-bundle
```

However, to run your new app, you will still need to do a `bundle install` anyway, so you should determine why it's taking so long.

Comment: one use case of skipping bundle is he wants to have gems installed in a specific `gemset` which will be created after generating Rails app.

Comment: another use case is when you want to run with '--verbose' flag

Answer (score -1):

To solve your issue more permanently, create a regular rails app. Yes, I know it might take a long time for you.

```
rails new ggg --database=mysql
```

Then, inside the app, do a bundle install --system:

```
cd ggg
bundle install --system
```

This will copy all the gems you are having to install locally inside the project folder to your system folder. From now, it will be quick to create new projects.