# Understanding rails command option argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to better understand rails command command line `help option` like,

```
rails new --help
```

It show's us the number of options on command line.

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /home/vinay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file
```

And If I triggered `rails new test_1 -B`. It would skip bundle install.

> Here what is `[--no-skip-bundle]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes we already have gems installed (by executing `gem install` or because we have created a rails project before) and it is a little annoying to wait for `bundle install` execution each time we create a new project. In that case, we can skip bundle execution by adding `--skip-bundle` to command when creating a rails project.

`--no-skip-bundle` is just the opposite for `--skip-bundle`

**Other Use Case**: other use case of skipping bundle is if you wants to have gems installed in a specific [gemset](http://rubyinrails.com/2013/12/what-is-gemset-in-ruby-on-rails/) which will be created after generating Rails app. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378501/how-to-remove-bundle-install-command-during-the-project-creation-in-rails-3-1#comment-33842343))