# How to go about creating rails app without running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please I am new to rails, and i observe that anytime i generate a new rails app, I must go online and run ***bundle install*** before I can start working on the app, please is there any way to to it without going online?

Comment: `bundle install` installs the required gems for you app, that is mentioned in your Gemfile. Why you want to skip it?

Comment: Still you could look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7379587/2968762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `rails new` with the `--skip-bundle` option to generate the code without running `bundle install`:

```
rails new . --skip-bundle
```

There are a lot more options for `rails new`, which you can learn about by executing:

```
rails new --help
```